# AutoComplete search in swiftui not working

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-environment, swiftui-form, swiftui-texteditor

I have a TextField as search box.I want to make it autosearch i.e whenever i will enter a letter in the TextField, i should get the result without press a enter.Here is my code:

```
TextField("Search", text: $searchText, 
    onEditingChanged: {
        isEditing in
        print("isEditing")
        //my method to fetch result
    }, onCommit: {
        print("onCommit")
    })
```

But it's not working like that.After entering a letter in the textfield, when i press enter, first it prints "onCommit" and after that it prints "isEditing".Any idea how can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
TextField("Search", text: Binding(
    get: { searchText },
    set: { newVal in
    searchText = newVal
    // my method to fetch result
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

However you could consider this alternative approach, to do a search box:

```
let langDictionary: [String:String] = [
    "af"  :  "Afrikaans",
    "al"  :  "Albanian",
    "ar"  :  "Arabic",
    "az"  :  "Azerbaijani",
    "bg"  :  "Bulgarian",
    "ca"  :  "Catalan",
    "cz"  :  "Czech",
    "da"  :  "Danish",
    "de"  :  "German",
    "el"  :  "Greek",
    "en"  :  "English",
    "eu"  :  "Basque",
    "fa"  :  "Persian (Farsi)",
    "fi"  :  "Finnish",
    "fr"  :  "French",
    "gl"  :  "Galician",
    "he"  :  "Hebrew",
    "hi"  :  "Hindi",
    "hr"  :  "Croatian",
    "hu"  :  "Hungarian",
    "id"  :  "Indonesian",
    "it"  :  "Italian",
    "ja"  :  "Japanese",
    "kr"  :  "Korean",
    "la"  :  "Latvian",
    "lt"  :  "Lithuanian",
    "mk"  :  "Macedonian",
    "no"  :  "Norwegian",
    "nl"  :  "Dutch",
    "pl"  :  "Polish",
    "pt"  :  "Portuguese",
    "pt_br"  :  "Portuguese (Brazil)",
    "ro"  :  "Romanian",
    "ru"  :  "Russian",
    "se"  :  "Swedish",
    "sk"  :  "Slovak",
    "sl"  :  "Slovenian",
    "es"  :  "Spanish",
    "sr"  :  "Serbian",
    "th"  :  "Thai",
    "tr"  :  "Turkish",
    "uk"  :  "Ukrainian",
    "vi"  :  "Vietnamese",
    "zh_cn"  :  "Chinese Simplified",
    "zh_tw" :   "Chinese Traditional",
    "zu"  :  "Zulu"]


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchQuery = ""
    @State var langArr = Array(langDictionary.values.sorted {$0 < $1})
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 30)  {
            TextField("Search", text: $searchQuery).padding(10)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    // move the search system here
                    ForEach(langArr.filter{self.searchFor($0)}.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 }), id: \.self) { lang in
                        Text(lang).padding(10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding(10)
    }
    
    private func searchFor(_ txt: String) -> Bool {
        return (txt.lowercased(with: .current).hasPrefix(searchQuery.trim().lowercased(with: .current)) || searchQuery.trim().isEmpty)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I would like to use the Combine framework's `Just` subscriber. Please check the `.onReceive` part to understand. This is a tested code. `Just` is a publisher that emits an output to each subscriber just once, and then finishes.

So when it detects the change it publishes and `.onReceiver` capture that changes.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct TestView: View {
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $searchText,
                onEditingChanged: {
                    isEditing in
                    print("isEditing")
                    //my method to fetch result
                }, onCommit: {
                    print("onCommit")
                })
                .onReceive(Just(searchText), perform: { _ in
                    if searchText.count > 0 {
                        print("Text entered: \(searchText). Now do whatever you want")
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmud.It is working but i am facing a problem also.Inside the if condition of onReceive, i am calling my method to get the search result and after getting the result when i am showing, the method inside onReceive is calling continuously.

Comment: Can you please just copy and paste the code to test. In my test, it's working without any issue. Or you can share your code in simple form, which I can test.